# The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0. Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

C:/Users/LENOVO/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2bcd0a6b95744b6f0ee26f9336bd22eb/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0-beta01.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
      google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // Add the dependency for the Performance Monitoring plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a solution for this issue. can see it in this link >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260986/the-binary-version-of-its-metadata-is-1-8-0-expected-version-is-1-6-0/75269801#75269801

Comment: it worked for me, when i just added as   ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0' and increased the gradle version as suggested by android studio.

Answer (score 8):

Recently, I faced a similar issue on creating a new project in Android studio with Compose Material3 template.

So I upgraded below libraries/plugins solve my issue. I also attached my gradle files for reference.

> `kotlin version to 1.8.0`
>
> `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'`
>
> `compose_version to 1.3.1`

**build.gradle(app)**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.appname'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha05'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.3'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Comment: this solution worked for me using gradle 7.5, AGP 7.4.0

Answer (score 4):

Probably updating Android Studio will do the trick.
If you have to use older version of Android Studio, try to downgrade both kotlin and appcompat dependencies.

I have changed from:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```

to

```
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

And this resolved my issue.

Comment: But now you have out of date dependencies

Answer (score 2):

I had to update kotlin and compose versions to the newest one.
Here is the compatibility list for kotlin and compose versions: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

In build.gradle(:app) in android{}:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.5.3'
}
```

Problem happened to me after adding dagger hilt so that was important too:

In build.gradle(:app) in dependencies{}:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.48'
```

In build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.48'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.10"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}
```

Comment: This helped me with the Kotlin 1.9.21 update. Had to make sure the version code in **build.gradle** here: 
`id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.21' apply false`
matched the compatible compose version as listed in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

This project contains a few incompatible or even dangerous things, that also lead you to the problem you're having:

- `jcenter()` is not in service anymore, so it should be replaced by `mavenCentral()` or your dependencies will not be correctly resolved.
- You specify both Kotlin `1.4.32` (no longer maintained) and `1.6.10` (no longer ideal, but still usable) and the classes will definitely not be compatible between them.
- Some of your other dependencies might be even newer and use Kotlin `1.8.0`, so your older runtimes won't be able to read their metadata.

Comment: jcenter is read-only indefinitely. Using it won't prevent dependencies from being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want or can't update Kotlin, you can simply set appropriate Android Gradle Plugin Version in project structure. (File->Project Structure) in android studio, it will look for modules compatible with your current Kotlin version rather than downloading the latest ones built with higher Kotlin versions.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was part of Arpit Patel's answer. I started getting this error when I upgraded my kotlin plugin and modules dependencies.

To solve this, I just had to upgrade the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android` plugin version to `1.8.0` in project's build.gradle.

Following are my `build.gradle` files after the fix:

root build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    // ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

module's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
}
```

Hope this helps people with the new root build.gradle format where classpath isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, this error will appear when two dependencies are updated :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'

to new version 1.11.0 (sdk 34)

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

to new version 1.12.0 (sdk 34)
```

There are two ways:

1- **Back** to the previous version

2- **Change** the version of **Kotlin plugins for Gradle** to Version 2.0.0-Beta2 [(latest)](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) but **1.8.0** can be acceptable

```
plugins{    
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `builed.gradle` of the project,
Updating the version number from this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}
```

to this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

finally solved the problem.

Answer (score -3):

I was getting this error - but it had a different cause.

Make sure that in `settings.gradle` you are using:

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')
```

And not:

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
```

Hope this helps someone else out.