# The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: android, kotlin

I had this problem yesterday and 4 developers working together had this problem as well.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

> /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2dce81f10515217cc4bd96ea20deb014/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

and when i remove kotlin all related settings will not encounter this problem

I would like help to solve this problem by using kotlin v1.6.0

Comment: I had a similar issue after upgrading to Kotlin stdlib 1.8.0 and solved it by the suggestions from: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies  Specifically for me it was the `implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0'))` that fixed it

Answer (score 8):

I had a solution for config this issue.

Step 1: Upgrade Kotlin v1.6.0 to v1.80

> Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Project

Step 2: Upgrade Gradle plugin v7.0.2

> Tools -> AGP Upgrade assistant -> Select (7.0.2) -> Run Selected Step

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by clicking File>Invalidate Caches
Also you can
Upgrade Kotlin

using ..

Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Project

And Upgrade Gradle plugin

Tools -> AGP Upgrade assistant -> Select (version) -> Run Selected Step

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75269801/12110705)

Also the reason for this error might be

The user updates the Kotlin version of the plugin to match the IDE version per the warning.
[image]

The user updates the android build tools gradle plugin per the warning
Warning about android build tools
[image]

This is the WRONG version!

Now you don't have any warnings, but the version suggested is 7.1.3 which is not the latest. (I don't know why it suggests this older version) 7.3.1 is currently the latest and is meta data 1.7.1, so it will match the Kotlin version of 1.7.20 (which is also metadata 1.7.1)

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/12110705)

Answer (score 0):

First step: ensure that kotlin and kotlin-stdlib use the same version, especially 1.6.0

Second step: try to clean caches by the following console commands

```
rm -R ~/.gradle/caches
git clean -xdf -e local.properties -e .idea
```